# Why does the assigned material not stay on the selected faces?

Tags: materials, faces

[image]

I used the knife tool on this cylinder to make two slanted cuts. I wanted to assign a color to the faces between the two cuts. I went to materials, assigned a color and saw that the green color goes **beyond** both edges.

As I said before, I want the color to stay **between** the edges.

Why is that? And what can I do to correct it or prevent it?

Comment: Hello ! It happens when you have a subdivision surface modifier enabled on your object.

Comment: Like @Gorgious said, the material cannot really exceed faces, but if those faces you see in _Edit Mode_ (which you can assign the material to) are subdivided by a modifier, the newly created faces can inherit the material from the original face. To prevent it either bevel the slanted edges just a little so that you have two edges close together - which can be a problem for a smooth surface and only decreases the effect by exceeding it less  - or you have to apply the modifier and add the material to the new geometry. If there's a different problem, your screenshot is much too tiny to discover.